# How to Test Print-preview of Chrome browser using Chrome webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have tried using switching between windows using

```
    String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
    <code to print>
    for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles())
         driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
    driver.findElement(By.className("cancel")).click();
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);
```

This hangs my test case execution after it opens the print preview page.

Also tried with javascript executor method, but no use.

```
   JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
   jse.executeScript("window.close()", "");
```

Please suggest if it's possible to do so.

Comment: This is out of Selenium's scope.

Comment: Found a solution for this. Worked out with Sikuli-api

Comment: Can you please share the solution in detail? That would be a great help! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question. I used below code snippet.

```
 //Create a Region for Desktop Screen
 ScreenRegion s = new DesktopScreenRegion();
 //Find target with below Image in Desktop Screen
 Target target = new ImageTarget(new File("Image.png"));
 ScreenRegion r = s.find(target);
 // Create a mouse object
 Mouse mouse = new DesktopMouse();
 // Use the mouse object to click on the center of the target region
 mouse.click(r.getCenter());
```

With the help of this snippet you would able to find the `print` or `cancel` and do the mouse click event and proceed with selenium tests. This was possible using `sikuli API`