# How to automate upload multiple files using sikuli and selenium webdriver in java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, sikuli-script

I am new with sikuli, Unable to generate Sikuli script for upload functionality for web application.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23213535/how-to-test-print-preview-of-chrome-browser-using-chrome-webdriver - Similar way to begin with

Answer (score 0):

Please note that typically, you can automate file upload scenario using Selenium only, no need for Sikuli.
For uploading a file you just need to call`sendKeys()` method (with file path as argument) on the WebElement that is displayed for file uploading. Code goes like this:

```
//Put this for textbox near to upload button
driver.findElement(By.id("id_or_other_locator_goes_here")).sendKeys("file_path_goes_here");
```

And then click the upload button:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("locator_for_upload_button")).click(); // Click Upload button
```

Sikuli :

I have used Sikuli to automate file download scenario in IE and below are the steps for this:

1. First capture image of Save button in File download dialog box and save it
2. Put Sikuli jar in your Java project
3. Use following code snippet

// Code:

```
//Save the file in Downloads directory by using on Sikuli

ScreenRegion s = new DesktopScreenRegion();
Target target = new ImageTarget(new File("SavedImagePath.png"));
ScreenRegion r = s.find(target);
Mouse mouse = new DesktopMouse();   
if (r != null) {
    mouse.click(r.getCenter());
    Thread.sleep(5000);
} else {
    System.out.println("Unable to click using Sikuli")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks sandeep!

tried below script using Screen and Pattern class of Sikuli to capture desktop based file from open folder windows at run time and it works!!

```
                     String FileToUpload = "/location of file to upload/"
                     String fileNameLoc = "/fileName_input sikuli image location"
                     String openButtonLoc = "/Open button sikuli image location/"

                     //Code to perform action using action using sikuli script
                     Screen src = new Screen();
                     src.setAutoWaitTimeout(80);
                     Pattern fileName = new Pattern(fileNameLoc).similar((float) 0.5);
                     if (src.exists(fileName, 10) != null)
                     {
                          System.out.println("File Name Pattern exist..");
                          Match match = src.getLastMatch();
                          match.find(fileName);
                          match.click(fileName);
                          match.type(fileName, FileToUpload);
                          match.setAutoWaitTimeout(50);
                     }
                     else
                     {
                          System.out.println("File Name pattern not found on screen..");
                     }

                     Pattern open = new Pattern(openButtonLoc).similar((float) 0.5);
                     if (src.exists(open, 5) != null)
                     {
                          System.out.println("Open Button pattern exist..");
                          Match match = src.getLastMatch();
                          match.find(open);
                          match.click(open);
                          match.setAutoWaitTimeout(30);
                     }
                     else
                     {
                          System.out.println("Open buton pattern not found on screen..");
                     }
```